# Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in CLI mode

Tags: php, sqlite, sql

12.04 AMD 64

```
apt-get install sqlite php5-cli php5-sqlite

php -r '$x = sqlite_open();' PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: You probably need to configure PHP to actually use the sqlite module.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SQLite3::open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php) instead.

`sqlite_open` is an old function, deprecated in PHP 5.4